# C# to VB.Net Conversion Error

Tags: asp.net, c#-to-vb.net, webmethod

I have this piece of code where I'm trying to convert the below C# code to Vb.Net and place it in my content place holder and it gives me error as

```
Statement cannot appear outside of a method body/multiline lambda.
```

Can any one provide me the correct syntax.

Here is the C# script:

```
<script runat="server">
    [WebMethod()]
    public static bool CheckUserName(string userName)
    {
        return (Membership.GetUser(userName) != null);
    }
</script>
```

I'm using tangible converter and it's conversion to VB.Net is here:

```
<script runat="server"> (WebMethod()) public static Boolean CheckUserName(String userName)
        Return (Membership.GetUser(userName) IsNot Nothing)
</script>
```

And the entire code is here:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Services" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
    [WebMethod()]
    public static bool CheckUserName(string userName)
    {
        return (Membership.GetUser(userName) != null);
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Create User</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var _txtUserName;
    var _divStatus;
    var _timerHandle;

    function pageLoad()
    {
        _txtUserName = $get('<%= CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName").ClientID %>');
        _divStatus = $get('<%= CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("divStatus").ClientID %>');
        $addHandler(_txtUserName, "keyup", onKeyUp);
    }

    function pageUnload()
    {
        $removeHandler(_txtUserName, "keyup", onKeyUp);
        clearTimer();
    }

    function onKeyUp(e)
    {
        setupTimer();
    }

    function setupTimer()
    {
        clearTimer();
        _timerHandle = window.setTimeout(checkUserName, 500)
    }

    function clearTimer()
    {
        if (_timerHandle != null)
        {
            window.clearTimeout(_timerHandle);
            _timerHandle = null;
        }
    }

    function checkUserName()
    {
        if (_txtUserName.value.length > 2)
        {
            _divStatus.innerHTML = 'Checking...';
            _divStatus.style.color = 'black';
            PageMethods.CheckUserName(_txtUserName.value, OnCheckUserNameComplete, OnCheckUserNameError, _txtUserName.value);
        }
    }

    function OnCheckUserNameComplete(result, userContext)
    {
        if (result == true)
        {
            _divStatus.innerHTML = String.format('\'{0}\' is already taken', userContext);
            _divStatus.style.color = 'red';
        }
        else
        {
            _divStatus.innerHTML = String.format('\'{0}\' is available', userContext);
            _divStatus.style.color = 'green';
        }
    }

    function OnCheckUserNameError(e)
    {
        _divStatus.innerHTML = e.get_message();
        _divStatus.style.color = 'red';
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager  ID="theScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server">
                <WizardSteps>
                    <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <table border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2">Sign Up for Your New Account</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <div id="divStatus" runat="server"></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Question">Security Question:</asp:Label></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Question" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuestionRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Question" ErrorMessage="Security question is required." ToolTip="Security question is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">Security Answer:</asp:Label></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Answer" ErrorMessage="Security answer is required." ToolTip="Security answer is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:CompareValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color: red">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <CustomNavigationTemplate>
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="5" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                                <tr align="right">
                                    <td align="right" colspan="0">
                                        <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Create User" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </CustomNavigationTemplate>
                    </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                    <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server">
                    </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
                </WizardSteps>
            </asp:CreateUserWizard>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The original code is from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/06/30/Check-User-Name-in-Ajax-way.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, this converter that you are using seems to kinda suck. I mean this `public static Boolean CheckUserName` that it spitted to you doesn't look much like VB.NET code to me.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/VB" runat="server">
    <WebMethod> _
    Public Shared Function CheckUserName(userName As String) As Boolean
        Return (Membership.GetUser(userName) IsNot Nothing)
    End Function
</script>
```

Also don't forget to change the language in your `Page` directive on the top of your webform.

And don't rely on automatic converters. Rely on your knowledge and skills when dealing with code.

Comment: @Darin-That did the trick-Thank you so much.Yes Just I was trying to see whether it's working fine or not I haven't gone too deep to look into that.Anyways I will dig it now.